# How to use Pandas to read the old_Excel xls format?

Tags: pandas, xls

How I can use Pandas to import an old format XLS file (Not XLSX)?

I downloaded an XLS file from United Nation Exchange Rate (https://treasury.un.org/operationalrates/OpRatesExport.php)

Even trying different methods, I cannot get Pandas to import the file. I had tried these:
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel('D:\000_DOWNLOAD\downloaded.xls', skiprows=1)
df
error code: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

It has a different error code when I added 'engine='xlrd':
df = pd.read_excel('D:\000_DOWNLOAD\downloaded.xls', skiprows=1,engine='xlrd')
df
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\nAfghan'

I have the same XLRDError code even when changing skiprows=1 to  skiprows=[0,1,2]

I would be grateful for any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download file from that site appears to be a `.xml` file (not `.xls`). What combination of options are you selecting to get `.xls`?

I was able to download a file that could be read in via [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html).

Here is the code that worked for me

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('downloaded.xml')

# then if you want to save it in a different format:
df.to_csv('downloaded.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, Cameron.  I am a newbie. Could you please send your codes how you read the file in xml. I have never used xml in my life and do not understand it. After reading  the xml into df, can I save it into either csv or json file? The United Nation website allow to download either in XLS or XML file. Thank you again!

Comment: just updated my answer for you

Comment: Did this approach end up working for you?

Comment: Yes, Cameron. I got it to work. I am very grateful for your help.  Since I do not understand xml.  read xml then convert it into csv.  Then I try to clean the data up.  Here are my codes.  
    df_xml = pd.read_xml('D:\\000_DOWNLOAD\\downloaded.xml')
    df_xml.to_csv('D:\\000_DOWNLOAD\\fx_downloaded.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv('D:\\000_DOWNLOAD\\fx_downloaded.csv',index_col=False) 
    df = df.drop(['id','element'], axis=1)
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]],axis = 1)
    df.to_csv('D:\\FMP_DATA\\fx_un_xchg_rates.csv', index = False, header = False, sep ='~')

Comment: That's fantastic to hear! Glad I could help- since this did answer your question would you mind upvoting it and selecting it as the "correct answer" so that other's with the same/similar questions can quickly see what might work for them?

Comment: I just did that. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not a valid Excel file. It's just a plain text file. Excel can open it, but will give you a warning that it's the wrong format.

You can parse it as a text file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    "downloaded.xls",
    sep="\t",
    header=None,
    names=["Country", "CurrencyDescription", "CurrencyCode", "Date", "ExchangeRate"],
    parse_dates=["Date"]
)

for col in df.select_dtypes("object"):
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
```

Change the column names as needed.

Comment: Hi Code Different,  I used your code but I keep getting "ValueError: embedded null character" I think the very first row of the XLS file is blank. I added "skiprows= 0" and "skiprows= [0,1,2,0]" , but still get the same "embedded null character." Should I add some other codes to solve this error? Thank you so much for taking the time to help!